# stored procedure progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a huge stored procedure and I want to create a progress bar for it on asp.net VB front-end. So, as suggested before on stackoverflow, I have to use additional status table and timer on front-end. Then, I have to call another stored procedure that will return current status of stored proc. But I cannot do async procedure calls on sql server from front-end. What are the settings I should try to set on sql server end to allow asynchronious procedures? ANd on the front-end it looks like my program stops executing when it hits stored procedure #1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually you don't need to start second proc in assync. 
Just open yet another connection on c# side and periodically (here can be used low-priority thread or Timer) call yours #2 - that checks progress.